# Array null out the function

Tags: arrays, xcode, function, parsing, block

I am trying to print the contents of the array that I fill with parse, but outside of the function the array is empty and print Null. How can I fix this? thanks

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse {
PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bracciali"];

[retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {



        NSArray *array = [objects objectAtIndex:0];//Selects the first "object" from all the "objects"
        array = [array valueForKey:@"NomeDispositivo"];//Makes a NSArray from the "pairs" values
        colorsArray = [array mutableCopy];//Converts the array to a NSMutableArray

        NSLog(@"%@", colorsArray); // PRINT THE ARRAY,,,


    }

}];


NSLog(@"%@", colorsArray); //PRINT NULL

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is run in a background thread (if its name is anything to go by) so when this statement is executed:

```
NSLog(@"%@", colorsArray); //PRINT NULL
```

This background "job" hasn't completed (or possibly even started).

If you want to schedule something to happen once `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` has finished then you will need to supply it with a *completion handler* (another block), and have `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` call that, probably supplying an error code to tell the block if it was successful or not.  You can then perform your logging/whatever else in that *completion handler*.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse 
{
      PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bracciali"];

     __block NSArray *array = nil; 
     [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) 
    {
        array = [objects objectAtIndex:0];//Selects the first "object" from all the "objects"
        array = [array valueForKey:@"NomeDispositivo"];//Makes a NSArray from the "pairs" values
        colorsArray = [array mutableCopy];//Converts the array to a NSMutableArray

        NSLog(@"%@", colorsArray); // PRINT THE ARRAY,,,    
    }

}];


NSLog(@"%@", colorsArray); //PRINT NULL

}
```

In your code the scope of the `array` object was within the block. Move the `array` object outside the block as I did above.

Should work!